# Showing a set of functions in the collection of continuous functions on $\left[0,1\right]$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have a set $$A=\left\{f\in\mathcal{C}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)\restriction-1\le f^{\prime}\left(x\right)\le2,f\left(0\right)=0\right\}$$ where $\mathcal{C}\left(\left[0,1\right]\right)$ is endowed with the supremum norm. I need to show that this set is closed. I have done everything except show that a sequence of functions $\left(f_{n}\right)$ that converges to $f_{*}$ has a sequences of derivatives $\left(f_{n}^{\prime}\right)$ that converge uniformly to $g=f_{*}^{\prime}$. This way I can show that $$-1\le f_{*}^{\prime}\left(x\right)\le 2$$
I want to say that since $$-1\le\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}^{\prime}\left(x\right)\le2$$ then $$-1\le g\left(x\right)\le2$$ But, I am not sure how to show that this sequence of derivatives converges uniformly so that I can say $g=f_{*}^{\prime}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given you have uniform convergence, for any fixed $x,y$, for n large enough you should be able to approximate $f(x)-f(y)$ by $f_n(x)-f_n(y)$ . Now dividing by $x-y$ (and using continuity) should tell you that slopes should converge too. Is there some reason this line of reasoning did not work?

Comment: Okay thank you. To be honest, I didn't think about doing it like this. I appreciate your help. If you would like, you may post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer and ask me if you have any more queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix any point $x$.

Given you have uniform convergence, and given for close enough $x,y$,  the term $h_n(x)=\frac{f_n(x)−f_n(y)}{x-y}$ is absolutely bounded for all $n$ by the bound on slopes, for large enough $n$, you could make $h(x)=\frac{f(x)−f(y)}{x-y}$ converge to $h_n(x)$ uniformly for that interval.

Given the uniform convergence above, you should be able to take limits ($n \to \infty $ and $y \to x$) in the order that you want, to show what you want to show.

Comment: I don't follow this. And I would like to add that the exact approach of the OP will not work. For example, let $g_n(x)=((x+1)/3)^n$ and $f_n(x)= \int_0^x g_n(t)dt$. Even though $(f_n)_n$ converges in norm to $0$,  no sub-sequence of $(f'_n)_n=(g_n)_n$ converges uniformly.

Comment: I would be happy to clarify the part you are not sure about.

Comment: For the continuity of derivative you only need uniformity around an interval of x, which you can get from what is provided. Is this where you disagree? I start by fixing a small interval around x (x,y being close enough, such that I can use the bound on derivative to get a bound on general slope)

Comment: In my first comment I had the domain and range mixed up. I should have $g_n(x)=x^n$, However I can,and will, give a counter-example: A sequence in $A$ that converges uniformly to a non-differentiable function. This will have to wait because it's 5 a.m. here.

Answer (score 0):

COUNTER-EXAMPLE. Consider a Koch snowflake curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

We will take a "small" snowflake: $f:[0,1]\to [0,1/6]^2$, with $f(0)=(0,0)$,  is the uniform limit of  a sequence $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1/6]$ of piecewise-linear continuous functions such that $\|f_n(x)-f_n(y)\|\leq |x-y|/2$ for all $n$ and for all $x,y\in [0,1],$ and with $f_n(0)=(0,0)$.

We can "smooth" the "corners" of each $f_n$  to get a sequence $g_n$ that also converges uniformly to $f,$ retaining the property that $\|g_n(x)-g_n(y)\|\leq |x-y|/2$, with the important additional property that, with $g_n(x)=(A_n(x),B_n(x)),$  the function $A_n(x)$ is differentiable, with $|A'_n(x)|\leq 1/2$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. And also $g_n(0)=(0,0).$

Now with $f(x)=(A(x),B(x)),$  the function $A(x)$ is the uniform limit of $(A_n)_n.$  But $A(x)$ is nowhere-differentiable.

So the function $A(x)$ is in the closure of the set $A$ but not in the set $A.$

Comment: Are you sure that this lies within our set $A$ to begin with? The set $A$ requires that our function $f$ must be differentiable for all $x\in\left[0,1 \right]$. I also don't know what you mean by "smooth the corners" to make it somehow differentiable on $\left[0,1\right]$

Comment: Each $A_n$ belongs to the set $A.$ The $ f$ in my A is not the $f$ of the Q.  For each $n$ the set of points $P_n \subset [0,1]$ where $f_n$ is not differentiable  is finite. We can  replace the values of $f_n$  in a sufficiently small nbhd of each $x\in P_n$ with a smooth-valued function, such that the result of these replacements   still meets all the  other criteria

Comment: What am I missing then? This problem was given by my professor, and he said we could show it was compact by using the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem and that we needed to show that the set was closed, equicontinuous, and pointwise compact. But from what you've shown, the set is not closed.

Comment: Arzela-Ascoli is that a closed subset of C[0,1] is compact iff it is bounded in norm and equicontinuous.  You should check with the prof.  We can't both be right.